# Passing a PHP variable into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP variable that I am declaring upon loading the page, and want to use it in a JavaScript/jQuery function that loads upon a button click.

I have the following on my index.php page:

```
// Creating a random name for a file and creating it. Working properly.
$fname = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
$file = fopen("temp/" .$fname, 'w');
```

And when I click a button, the following JavaScript function should run:

```
//Use the generated filename in the JavaScript function
var fname = <?php echo $fname; ?>;
var fileName = "temp/" + fname;
```

My understanding is that the PHP variable is outside of the scope of the JavaScript function, since I believe this is the way it should be done.

Can you please help with this?

Comment: did you tried like `var fname = "<?php echo $fname; ?>";`

Comment: since it's a string ^ check your console also and make sure that file's a `.php` extension too

Comment: When using quotes my console is interpreting it as a string so it tries to look for a file named "<?php echo $fname; ?>" :(

Comment: Are you in a PHP file?

Comment: I am trying to assign the PHP variable in a .js file for a JavaScript function, which makes it tricky :(

Comment: If you really need it to be in a javascript file, you could make a <script> block in a PHP file, have it echo out the variable, then use it in a later script, but that's not really a good way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP generates a page and presents it to a browser. As far as the browser is concerned, by the time the page is received, PHP is finished. So to answer your question, that should work, since PHP will essentially just spit out the text on to the page, which will act as normal. That is, unless I am terribly misinformed.

The "scope" of a PHP variable is long gone by the time Javascript gets to run, so that isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try do this. in a php file of course.

```
var fname = '<?php echo $fname; ?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an extension on your filename:

```
$extension = ".txt";
$fname = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7).$extension;
$file = fopen("temp/" .$fname, 'w');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the missing apostroph like anant kumar singh mentioned.
I tested the following code in a webpage:

```
<?php
        $fname = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
        $file = fopen("temp/" .$fname, 'w');
    ?>
    <html>
    <head
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        var fname = "<?php echo $fname; ?>";
        var fileName = "temp/" + fname;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would assume that this will indeed work when the PHP file and the JS function are called one below another. It doesn't work for my current setup because I tried it :(

Comment: Eh, way too long for the commentbox. I copied my reply to justpasteit.it:

http://justpaste.it/lzct

Comment: got it Neekoy, the problem is that your javascript click function isnt in a php file. so the interpreter will not recognize "<?php ?> " code as valid code. Can't you define the .click function inside the php file? Another way on http://phpjs.org/functions/md5/ you can find also a MD5 function for javascript than you don't need the php file name at all.

Comment: thinking well, a quick 'n dirty way would be, to rename your javascript.js to javascript.php and change the line <script src="javascript.js></script> to <script> <?php include_once("javascript.php"); ?></script>